# Robot framework: how to use "Set Variable If" without assigning default value(None) if condition not met

Tags: robotframework

I am new to robotframework.

Here I am parsing the response using robotframework FOR loop and Set Variable If keyword. but as I am calling in loop. one of the variable get set to None. I want to avoid that.

Response body

```
{
  'services': [
    {
      'service': 'postgres',,
      'replicationStatus': 'completed'
    },
    {
      'service': 'mongodb',
      'replicationStatus': 'completed'
    }
  ]
}
```

Parsing response_body

```
:FOR    ${item}  in    @{response_body["services"]}
\    Log    ${item}
\    ${mongodb_replication_status}=     Set Variable If    "${item['service']}"=="mongodb"    ${item['replicationStatus']}
\    ${postgres_replication_status}=    Set Variable If    "${item['service']}"=="postgres"   ${item['replicationStatus']}
Log    ${mongodb_replication_status}
Log    ${postgres_replication_status}
```

I get ouptput like below:

```
${mongodb_replication_status} = completed   
${postgres_replication_status} = None
```

Answer (score 3):

After each condition and value, the default value is given, in your case:

```
:FOR    ${item}  in    @{response_body["services"]}
\    Log    ${item}
\    ${mongodb_replication_status}=     Set Variable If    "${item['service']}"=="mongodb"    ${item['replicationStatus']}    default value
\    ${postgres_replication_status}=    Set Variable If    "${item['service']}"=="postgres"   ${item['replicationStatus']}    default value
Log    ${mongodb_replication_status}
Log    ${postgres_replication_status}
```

Another multi-condition example:

```
${variable_value}=    Set Variable If    ${var} == 1    one
...    ${var} == 2    two
...    other than one or two
```

If the default value is not available, the variable is assigned as `None`.

This is explained quite well in the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If).